# What kind of hard drive interface is this?

Tags: hard-drive, adapter

This an old hard drive from an Acer Travelmate laptop. It is a Seagate Momentus 5400.6 250 GB. It has 22 flat pins + 4 round pins. What kind of interface is this? And what adapter would I need to hook it up to a PC and copy the data?

[image: Old hard drive]

Comment: Lot easier with part numbers for the laptop and/or hard drive. An in focus picture of a clean connector would help as well.

Comment: It looks to be a standard sata connector with 4 jumper pins on the right. See sections 3.2 and 3.3 of https://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/notebook/momentus/5400.6%20(Wyatt)/100528359d.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an adapter for a common SATA interface to the notebook motherboard. Try to gently pull it off.